# WIX cannot install msipackage

Tags: xml, installation, wix

Hi i have a problem installing an MsiPackage.

I have the following code in my wix bootstrapper project:

```
<Chain>
    <MsiPackage Id="InstacalFull" Name="InstacalFull" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
    SourceFile="../Suite.SetupBootstrapper/3rdparty/InstaCal.msi"/>

    <MsiPackage Id="MainPackage" SourceFile="../Suite.SetupProject/bin/Release/Suite.SetupProject.msi" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Compressed="yes" Vital="yes" />
</Chain>
```

My application is succesfully installed but the MsiPackage with Id InstacalFull is not installed even though i can see it in the progress status in the installer wizard.

When i go to Programs and Features in Control Panel then i can see that it is not installed.

Is there a way to debug this? Is there a log file where i can see what is going on during the installation?

Or am i simply doing something completely wrong? Thx!

Comment: There should be a bootstrapper entry in ARP - it doesn't make sense to have both the bootsrapper entery and the MSI entry because the bootstrapper is managing the MSI package(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file is in the user's temp directory, typically C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp.

You need to set the `Visible` attribute to `true` on the `MsiPackage` to see an installed MSI package in Program and Features.

Comment: Thx this actually helped, sorry for the late reply. +1